Why does DataBricks give an API connection error when I try to use GPT-4o?
When trying to access AzureChatOpenAI via API in DataBricks I get: APIConnectionError: Connection error. The code works fine in Visual Studio Code.
I am using AzureChatOpenAI from langchain. Databricks highlights
response = model.invoke(messages, temperature=0)

as the error in the following code:
def get_categories_and_tone(review):
    messages = [
        SystemMessage(content="You are a helpful assistant that classifies customer reviews into predefined categories and determines the tone. Return the categories and the tone. Return it without any explanation. If the string: 'Lack.' appears in a review without any other words you must return a NaN as the tone"),
        HumanMessage(content=f"Classify the following review into one or more of these categories: {', '.join(categories)}.\n\nReview: \"{review}\"\nCategories:\nTone:")
    ]
    
    response = model.invoke(messages, temperature=0)
    response_content = response.content.strip().split('\n')
    
    categories_list = []
    tone = ""
    
    for line in response_content:
        if line.startswith("Categories:"):
            categories_list = line.replace('Categories: ', '').strip().split(', ')
        elif line.startswith("Tone:"):
            tone = line.replace('Tone: ', '').strip()
    
    return categories_list, tone

# Function to get the details if applicable
def get_details(categories_list, review):
    details = []
    for category in categories_list:
        if category in subcategories and subcategories[category]:
            possible_details = ', '.join(subcategories[category])
            messages = [
                SystemMessage(content="You are a helpful assistant that classifies customer reviews into predefined subcategories. Return only the subcategory name. Return it without any explanation."),
                HumanMessage(content=f"Based on the category '{category}', classify the following review into one of these details: {possible_details}\n\nReview: \"{review}\"\nDetail:")
            ]
            
            response = model.invoke(messages)
            response_content = response.content.strip()
            detail = response_content.replace('Detail: ', '').strip()
            details.append(detail)
        else:
            details.append("N/A")
    
    return details

# Main function for classifying an opinion
def classify_review(review):
    # Names to exclude
    categories_list, tone = get_categories_and_tone(review)
    #return categories_list, details, tone details removed as it deals with sub-categories
    return categories_list, tone

# Application of the function to classify every opinion
results = df['General Feedback, translated'].apply(classify_review)


check databrick network and  firewall configurations also check that your Databricks environment allows outbound traffic to Azure’s endpoints
